# how to set TextureRegion's centre point to rotate around. (libGdx)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to rotate a TextureRegion around its centre, however whenever I try to rotate it the rotation point is either the bottom corners of the Texture Region or a far part of the screen. 
this is the update method in my object class(the Texture Region will be emulating the movements of this Object.

```
public void update(float delta) {

   if (velocity.x < 0) {
        rotation -= 50*delta;

        if (rotation > 25) {
            rotation = 25;
        }
    }
    if (velocity.x > 0){
        rotation += 50*delta;

        if (rotation > 25) {
            rotation = 25;
        }
    }
}
```

this where I call the `draw` method to bring the Texture Region to screen

```
batcher.draw(AssetLoader.saum, sam.getX(), (gameHeight - (gameHeight / 3)), -(sam.getWidth()), (gameHeight - (gameHeight / 3)), -(sam.getWidth()), -(sam.getWidth()), 1, 1, sam.getRotation());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the `batch.draw` methods that has `originX` and `originY` parameters. 
`originX` and `originY` should be set to `width/2` and `height/2`.

[See methods here.](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html#i0)

Comment: this works perfectly! thank you very much, you saved me A LOT of hair tearing out :)